# How to edit storyboard in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode14

Every now and then, I see tutorials allowing to add components to a storyboard by clicking a plus sign on the right up corner of the editor:

[image]

Bu I do not have this button. And it seems that there is no menu available.

I have to say that I'm trying to modify the storyboard outside of any project by opening the file alone.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plus button should be available on the right side of Project Header Section[Tool Bar] as Shown in the image

[image]

Based on the selected file different screens will be opened when we click on the + button.
We can also use the keyboard shortcut `cmd+shift+L`

Verified on Xcode Version 14.1 (14B47b)

Update:

As this option is available on the Toolbar, it may not be available if the toolbar itself is hidden. To toggle the visibility of toolbar we can use the shortcut `cmd+option+T`

Comment: The toolbar was hidden! Thank you so much. So much time lost trying to find a solution.